# Cannot access ‘android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner’ which is a supertype of ‘io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity’

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to Flutter mixed development. Recently, I created a mixed project like [Integrate a Flutter module into your Android project](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) I use simplest method create a flutter_module by Android Studio. When look at  [Adding a Flutter screen to an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen?tab=default-activity-launch-kotlin-tab) , I write code like below:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
  startActivity(
FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(this)
 )
}
```

Then Android Studio Warn me "Cannot access ‘android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner’ which is a supertype of ‘io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity’. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies." on createDefaultIntent method. Any help is apprecated.

Android Studio 3.6.3

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 • channel

Answer (score 2):

It's seems just a android studio bug. Today I rearch more, have no result to. But when I try to run it , I found it can run. amazing.

Comment: Same for me. To clear the error, I had to go to File >> Invalidate Caches >> Invalidate and Restart, with only the "Clear VCS Log caches and indexes" checkbox selected.